# Prove that if $x,y,z$ are positive integers with $(x, y) = 1$ and $x^2+y^2 = z^4$, then $7|xy$ ; show that the condition $(x, y) = 1$ is necessary.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

Prove that if $x,y,z$ are positive integers such that $(x, y) = 1$ and $x^2+y^2 = z^4$, then $7|xy$ ; show that the condition $(x, y) = 1$ is necessary.

I am not able to approach this problem, can you give me some hints for starting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, show that one of $x,y$ must be even and the other must be odd (hint: if both are odd, consider the equation $\mod 8$).

WLOG $x$ is odd, $y$ is even. We have $x^2=(z^2-y)(z^2+y)$. 
Let $p|x$ be a prime. If $p$ divides both $(z^2-y), (z^2+y)$, it must divide $2y=(z^2+y)-(z^2-y)$, which is impossible as $p$ is odd and $(x,y)=1$. Hence $z^2-y, z^2+y$ are both squares (why?). 
Now consider all of the quadratic residues $\mod7$, which are $0, 1, 2, 4$,  and an easy case-checking shows that $7$ must divide one of $z^2-y, z^2+y, y$ and therefore it must divide $x$ or $y$.

For example, if $z^2 = 2 \mod7$, since $z^2 \pm y \equiv2 \pm y$ must be one of $0, 1, 2, 4 \mod 7$, we have that $y$ must  be one of $2, -2, 0 \mod 7$, which gives us that one of $z^2-y, z^2+y, y$ must be divisible by $7$. The other cases are similar.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$x^2+y^2=(z^2)^2$ is a Pythagorean triple

Every Pythagorean triple can be written generated by a pair of natural numbers $0<n<m$.  Then, $(m^2-n^2,2mn,m^2+n^2)$ is a triple, which is primitive iff $\gcd(m,n)=1$ and $2\mid mn$, and if $m$ and $n$ are both odd, $(\frac{m^2-n^2}{2},mn,\frac{m^2+n^2}{2})$ is also a triple which is primitive iff $\gcd(m,n)=1$.

Also, note that $(m,n,z)$ is also a Pythagorean triple if $2\mid mn$

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Yes, i am trying

Comment: FYI The "iff" phrasing part could be clarified. While I can tell that you're trying to describe 2 possible cases, that's not how saying " A iff B and C and if not C then iff D" works. It's better to explicitly say "A iff (B and C) or (not C and D)".

Comment: This does appear rather vague to me. What matters though is whether the OP is able to use the hint and finish.